# Using mv to move to another directory and rename at once

Tags: bash, find, mv

I would like to know every file which is +100Mb and hasn't been accessed in the last month, and I have written succesfully:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30
```

And now I want to move those files to a folder called /big-not-used changing its name as: `file_nameYYYYMMDD` where file_name is the orginal's file's name and YYYYMMDD is today's date, in year month day. For example `film.mkv` goes to `/big-not-used/film.mkv20161031`

My sentence would be:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 -exec mv {} /big-not-used/... \;
```

But I don't know how to append today's date at the file's name.
I have found that `date +%Y-%m-%d` outputs: `2016-10-31` which is useful.
Now the doubt is how to get this file's name?
Following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find

```
... -exec basename {} \;
```

Maybe?:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 -exec mv {} /big-not-used/$(basename {})$(date +%Y-%m-%d) \;
```

But it gives an error because basename is replying with the file's full path instead of its name which I would use:

```
${var##/*/}
```

to get the file's name, but the question is how do I insert what `basename {}` replies into the var in the previous expresion!?.

Maybe?

```
$(${$(basename {})##/*/})
```

But is says sintactic error near the unexpected '}'...

Answer (score 0):

You were getting close with:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 \
  -exec mv {} /big-not-used/$(basename {})$(date +%Y-%m-%d) \;
```

But without quoting, the shell expantion of `$(...)` constructs happens *before the `find` command executes*.  In other words, given the above command line, which actually gets executed is:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 \
  -exec mv {} /big-not-used/{}2016-10-30 \;
```

Because the result of `$(basename {})` is just `{}`, and that's why you end up with the full pathname.  Try this instead:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 \
  -exec sh -c 'mv {} /tmp/big-not-used/$(basename {})$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' \;
```

For testing things out, you can replace `mv` with `echo mv`, like this:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 \
  -exec sh -c 'echo mv {} /tmp/big-not-used/$(basename {})$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' \;
```

...and see what the generated commands look like.

Comment: Executing it gives it an output like: mv: cannot move "read.sh" to /tmp/big-not-used/read.sh2016-31-10 the file or directory doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried find / -size +100M -atime +30 -exec sh -c 'mkdir /big-not-used/$(basename{})$(date +%Y-%m-%d);  mv {} /big-not-used/$(basename {})$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' \;                            Unfortunately it outputs: mkdir: cannot create directory «/big-not-used/2016-10-30»: Doesn't exist file or direcotry
mv: cannot move «.» a «/big-not-used/.2016-10-30»: doesn't exist file or directory

Comment: If that's the actual command you used, you're missing a space between `basename` and `{}`.  The command as I wrote it *actually works* on my system (although I replace `mv` with `cp` because I don't actually want to move anything).

Answer (score 0):

I improved lark's solution a bit to make only a single `sh` call:

```
find / -size +100M -atime +30 -exec sh -c \
  'for f do mv "$f" /tmp/big-not-used/"$(basename "$f")$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"; done' sh {} +
```

Alternatively, without any `sh` calls at all:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  mv "$f" /tmp/big-not-used/"$(basename "$f")$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
done < <(find / -size +100M -atime +30)
```

(Latter under the assumption that the file names don't any newlines in them.)

For debugging you might want to add `-v` to `mv` (if it's supported).